# Websocket connection error - Visual studio apache cordova

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, websocket, apache-cordova

I'm creating a new Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio 2017. Most of the code is picked somewhere. It's not able to connect to a running server from the physical mobile phone. The same webpage served from a webserver is able to connect from the same mobile phone, so is not a firewall problem. Seems a permission problem.
As you can see for the Content-Security-Policy, I'm desperately trying to open everything.

index.html:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src: ws:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<title>WebSocket Test</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var wsUri = "ws://192.168.18.162:8352/ServidorMobil";
    var output;

    function init() {
        output = document.getElementById("output");
        testWebSocket();
    }
    function testWebSocket() {
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        websocket.onopen = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
        websocket.onclose = function (evt) { onClose(evt) };
        websocket.onmessage = function (evt) { onMessage(evt) };
        websocket.onerror = function (evt) { onError(evt) };
    }
    function onOpen(evt) {
        writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
        doSend("WebSocket rocks");
    }
    function onClose(evt) {
        writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
    }
    function onMessage(evt) {
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
        websocket.close();
    }
    function onError(evt) {
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
    }
    function doSend(message) {
        writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
        websocket.send(message);
    }
    function writeToScreen(message) {
        var pre = document.createElement("p");
        pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
        pre.innerHTML = message;
        output.appendChild(pre);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
</script>

<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also in the config.xml I have added:

```
<allow-intent href="ws:*" />
```

The only plugin installed is Whitelist (I reinstalled it again various times).
Thanks

Comment: The error function prints only "undefined".

Comment: The Javascript Console shows: WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.18.162:8352/ServidorMobil' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIEDindex.html (15,1)